# Returning a minimum index in an array in Julia

Tags: arrays, matlab, julia, minimum

I am converting some code from Matlab to Julia. In the matlab code:

```
[~,pStar] = min(min([dPlus,dMinus],[],2))
```

will return the minimum element in each row and output it in column form, then return the index (row) of the minimum element in the column just like:

```
>> M = [1,1,1;1,1,0;1,1,1]
M =
   1   1   1
   1   1   0
   1   1   1
>> min(M,[],2)
ans =
   1
   0
   1
>> [~,row] = min(min(M,[],2))
row =  2
```

My question is: what would be the Julia equivalent to this? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`indmin` returns the linear index of the minimum.  You can convert that to subscript form by using `ind2sub`, and extract the row from that:

```
julia> indmin(M)
8

julia> row, col = ind2sub(M, indmin(M))
(2, 3)

julia> row
2
```

This approach avoids iterating twice and creating an intermediate array.

*Update*: In Julia >= 0.7, this has changed to `argmin`, returning a `CartesianIndex` which you can directly use.  You can also use `findmin` to get both minimal value and its index.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers); if you found an answer that actually solved your problem satisfactorily, there's a checkmark you can use to mark it as "accepted".

Comment: Of course, I am getting an "invalid comprehension" error. I really would need you to see the rest of the code. Julia's debugging is so vague I don't have the slightest clue where it could be coming from. I am using a for loop to go through iterations of an experiment. No idea.

Answer (score 1):

One way is

```
julia> M = [1 1 1;1 1 0;1 1 1]
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1  1
 1  1  0
 1  1  1

julia> indmin(minimum(M, 2))
2
```

`minimum(X, dim)` finds the minima along the dimension `dim`.

`indmin(X)` returns the index of the minimum.

A faster way would be

`ind2sub(M, indmin(M))[1]`